# Setting table background does not change color of a sorted column

Tags: javascript, sorting, colors

This seems a very simple situation, but it mystifies me.

Javascript,   and Windows and Firefox FWIW.

I have a fairly large table, (110 rows, 15 columns). The cells have varied color backgrounds.
That color is set this standard way:

1. `tr[row].cells[col].style.background = "#f00";`   color depending on content.

A few cells (one long column that also gets sorted) are set the same way:

2. `tr[row].cells[col].style.background = "#ff0";`

When I want to clear all those colors at once (the entire table).

3. `I use tbl.style.background = "#fff";`

That table clear clears all cells set in **1**, which seems simple, but it changes none set in **2**  (same method).
Now that I think of it, it also does not clear the TH header row color, which is set in HTML and excluded in **1** and **2**, but the table clear does not clear it either,

My thought is that the situation is just that simple, but I cannot understand it. The table clear does in fact clear most cells (those in **1**).  Just not the one sorted column in **2**. Other columns are sorted too at times, but the last sorted column is the one that does not get color cleared.

My only solution was to come back and clear that column.

```
tr = tbl.rows;
col = sorted column that didn't get cleared (the previous sort actually)
for (row =     all rows    ) {
     tr[row].cells[col].style.background = "#ff0";
}
```

Which works, but why should that be necessary?
Why does `tbl.style.background = "#fff";`  only do some of them?    Specifically, not the last sorted column.
Both **1** and **2** are set just before the column sort.

This loop excludes the TH headers, so they retain the color, which the `tbl.styles` also did not clear.

I don't see how the sorting is involved with the colors, but it is the last sorted column that didn't get cleared, The sorting moves each whole TR row, not just the individual cells.

**EDIT:  Thank you Lajos Arpad**
But the table clear does clear all my individually set cells, EXCEPT for whatever column was last sorted, which I don't understand.  It seemed expedient to clear the table colors with the `tbl.style.background`,  and it almost works.  My ordering is to set various colors of all the cells in all columns, and then overwrite a different color on the column to be sorted.  I don't see any difference in that order, but that last column did write colors two times. Then it is sorted, but then next time, a table clear clears all, but that clear fails on whatever column was sorted.  And I can come back and correct that column, so it is working, but a mystery to me.

It doesn't seem to clear all of yours either, but  it does in fact clear my table background color set on almost all table rows and cells (all on 10 columns, around 1100 cells), which is good, EXCEPT it does not clear whatever one more column that was last sorted (about 110 cells). I fail to understand what sorting could have to do with the color.  Javascript sort is what moves the sorted rows.

I have tried commenting out the sort, and still the same problem, so the problem is of course Not the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a coloring for the table and another for the cells that you intend to colorize. So, when you want to paint or clear the table, you see that this is not being applied for cells that had a coloring of their own. The reason is that whatever the color of the table, it will not be applied to the cells having a coloring of their own, as that one will override it. I have created a snippet for you so you can play around it and I advise you to test this in action before reading the explanation.

```js
let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
let trs = tbl.querySelectorAll("tr");
let previousVal = -1;

function tableBackground(add) {
    tbl.style.backgroundColor = add ? "gray" : "white";
}

function colorize(val) {
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < trs.length; rowIndex++) {
        if (previousVal !== -1) trs[rowIndex].children[previousVal].style.backgroundColor = null;
        trs[rowIndex].children[val].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    previousVal = val;
}

function clearTableBackground() {
    tableBackground(false);
    if (previousVal !== -1) {
        for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < trs.length; rowIndex++) trs[rowIndex].children[previousVal].style.backgroundColor = null;
        previousVal = -1;
    }
}
```

```css
tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="1" onclick="colorize(0)">
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="colorize(1)">
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="colorize(2)">
<br>
<input type="button" value="table background" onclick="tableBackground(true);">
<input type="button" value="clear table background" onclick="tableBackground(false)">
<input type="button" value="clear table background for real" onclick="clearTableBackground()">
```

You see that we have two table clearers. The first clears the coloring of the table and is unsuccessful in removing the color from the cells which have overriden it. The second does the table clearing as well, but clears the colorized cells as well.

Comment: Thank you Lajos.  I edited a comment on the main body above.

Comment: @WayneF "It doesn't seem to clear all of yours either" I have two clear buttons: 1. "clear table background" which only clears the table background but not the colored cells and 2. "clear table background for real", which clears even the colorized cells. The reason for implementing both is to illustrate the difference between clearing only the background of the table and the colorized cells as well.

Comment: @WayneF if this is still not working out well for you, then I kindly ask you to create a snippet or a fiddle with a minimal reproducible example, so I will be able to test your problem on my own, play around it and fix it. I have implemented my snipped in the absence of such an example, but in order to fix your actual problem, if this was not enough, then we need you to make sure we have a reproducible example.

Comment: I would but have never done an online snippet to know how.  Your code selects one col and immediately clears the others. THEN you clear the background.  I don't know that it matters, but it's different than my my case of wondering why all my cells are not cleared.   My own arguments are not quite clear either. :)  These comments are too short for much detail, but will try in next one.  I do appreciate your help.

Comment: My code colors one sort col and runs and shows it, then the next call first clears background, resets all cell colors again, assumes the previous sorted col was cleared too, and colors another sort col col for next pass, And then next time ALL other cols ARE cleared except this last sorted col. (and except TH cells, which seems good). My recent change added a JS Object (grouped like a C structure, to pass globals into functions), but just now realized Objects are passed by reference instead of value. Saving last sort col # locally may be my problem but first try did not solved it yet.

Comment: @WayneF So, in this snippet, we have a feature to select a column. Once you select a column, if there was another column selected previously, then it's unselected, because I thought that you want a single column selected maximum. But we can easily allow the selection of multiple columns. Nevertheless, the actual issue is that if you select a color for the table and a color for cells, then the cell color overrides the table color for the cells where it is being applied. This is why simply changing the table color will not modify the color of the selected column

Comment: @WayneF if you click on table background, then click on 2, then you see that the table is colored and a column is also selected. Now, if you click on clear table background for real, then every coloring is cleared, because, besides the table color, the selection color is removed as well. Whereas, if you click on clear table background, then it will only remove the table background and it will fail to remove cell backgrounds if they existed.

Comment: @WayneF actually it's easy to create a snippet. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: Arpad, I have finally realized you are entirely correct.  I removed the tbl.styles.background clear, and was very surprised that made no difference at all to the colors. Filling in all cell colors was doing all the work. If interested, that app is at https://www.scantips.com/funds.html . Manually clearing the previous yellow sort column is working, and needed. It's complicated enough that I doubt I could isolate this effect in a snippet, but thanks for that link. I was clearly wrong about the table clear. Thanks much for hanging in there to make me understand.

Comment: @WayneF happy to help and I'm glad the issue was sorted out.